# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Ничто(ничего?) из этого не()достойно твоего внимания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь возможны различные варианты:

Нейтральный стиль: Ничего из этого недостойно (реже: не достойно) твоего внимания.

Книжный (возвышенный, устаревающий) стиль: Ничто из этого недостойно твоего внимания.

Сравнить: Ничто из этого  не было известно (встречается редко). Ничего из этого не сбылось.

Answer (score 0):

Задаем вопрос: что недостойно внимания? Ничто.